# Python: How two group and reshape a list given specific order of keys

Tags: python, list, group-by

This is my first question here, so sorry in advance that it might be not perfect. ;)

I have a list of image names. Each of the images was taken in a specific mode.
The modes are Q+,Q-,U+,U- (The Stokes parameter of an polarimetry image). So four images represent a full observation cycle. The list of files i have looks something like this.

```
[['file_name1','Q+', some other info, ...], 
['file_name2','Q+', some other info, ...], 
['file_name3','Q+', some other info, ...],
['file_name4','Q-', some other info, ...], 
['file_name5','Q-', some other info, ...],
['file_name6','Q-', some other info, ...], 
['file_name7','U+', some other info, ...], 
['file_name8','U+', some other info, ...],
['file_name9','U+', some other info, ...],
['file_name10','U-', some other info, ...], 
['file_name11','U-', some other info, ...], 
['file_name12','U-', some other info, ...]]
```

My problem is, that i need to group the data in a specific way for further processing.
In the end the data structure should look like this:

```
[[['file_name1','Q+', ...], 
['file_name4','Q-', ...], 
['file_name7','U+', ...],
['file_name10','U-', ...]],
[['file_name2','Q+', ...], 
['file_name5','Q-', ...], 
['file_name8','U+', ...], 
['file_name11','U-', ...]],
[['file_name3','Q+', ...],
['file_name6','Q-', ...], 
['file_name9','U+', ...], 
['file_name12','U-', ...]], ....]
```

I found no solution yet... but i think that maybe the python groupby can do it.

Comment: This is a list of lists. Its not terribly clear what your problem is, or what you have tried, so there is not much that we can debug. How does the input become the output? What is the logic? What methods are you trying? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby 

>>> zip(*[list(g) for _,g in  groupby(fn, key=lambda sl:sl[1])]) 
[(['file_name1', 'Q+', 'some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name4', 'Q-', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name7', 'U+', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name10', 'U-', ' some other info, ...']), 
 (['file_name2', 'Q+', 'some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name5', 'Q-', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name8', 'U+', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name11', 'U-', ' some other info, ...']), 
 (['file_name3', 'Q+', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name6', 'Q-', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name9', 'U+', ' some other info, ...'], 
  ['file_name12', 'U-', ' some other info, ...'])]
```

Comment: You are the man!!!! Thank you very much...This is what i was looking for. I just have to accept that my programming skills are low :D...

Comment: Thanks also @schwobaseggl who came up first with this answer but it is not shown here

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the first file name in each group must be together, then the second and so on (in other words if you can trust the order of the list of files, you can construct the grouped version quite easily by slicing with strides:

```
files = [
    ['file_name1','Q+', 'some other info, ...'], 
    ['file_name2','Q+', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name3','Q+', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name4','Q-', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name5','Q-', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name6','Q-', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name7','U+', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name8','U+', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name9','U+', 'some other info, ...'],
    ['file_name10','U-', 'some other info, ...'], 
    ['file_name11','U-', 'some other info, ...'], 
    ['file_name12','U-', 'some other info, ...']]

groupsize = 4
Ngroups = len(files)//groupsize

i = 0

result = sum([files[i::N] for i in range(0, Ngroups)], [])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Unfortunately i cant trust the order always. its hard to describe... also the number of images observed with Q+, Q- ... is not fixed. What is N in your code?